# Docusign API call errors PHP

Tags: docusignapi

Trying to set up Docusign using the example PHP code for [Requesting a signature via a template](http://iodocs.docusign.com/APIWalkthrough/requestSignatureFromTemplate). I have all my account details set up correctly and have tried adding the lines:

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST,false);
```

but i still keep getting errors :

accountId = xxxxxxx baseUrl = https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/accounts/1135802 error calling webservice, status is:0 error text is -->

I have also opened up the firewall to prevent any errors there

Any ideas what the error means

the code from Docusign is:

```
<?php
// Input your info here:
$email = "#######";         // your account email (also where this signature request will be sent)
$password = "#######";      // your account password
$integratorKey = "########";        // your account integrator key, found on (Preferences -> API page)
$recipientName = "#####";       // provide a recipient (signer) name
$templateId = "#######";        // provide a valid templateId of a template in your account
$templateRoleName = "Owner";    // use same role name that exists on the template in the console

// construct the authentication header:
$header = "<DocuSignCredentials><Username>" . $email . "</Username><Password>" . $password . "</Password><IntegratorKey>" . $integratorKey . "</IntegratorKey></DocuSignCredentials>";

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// STEP 1 - Login (to retrieve baseUrl and accountId)
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
$url = "https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/login_information";
$curl = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("X-DocuSign-Authentication: $header"));
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST,false);

$json_response = curl_exec($curl);
$status = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

if ( $status != 200 ) {
    echo "error calling webservice, status is:" . $status;
    exit(-1);
}

$response = json_decode($json_response, true);
$accountId = $response["loginAccounts"][0]["accountId"];
$baseUrl = $response["loginAccounts"][0]["baseUrl"];
curl_close($curl);

// --- display results
echo "\naccountId = " . $accountId . "\nbaseUrl = " . $baseUrl . "\n";

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// STEP 2 - Create and envelope using one template role (called "Signer1") and one recipient
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
$data = array("accountId" => $accountId, 
    "emailSubject" => "DocuSign API - Signature Request from Template",
    "templateId" => $templateId, 
    "templateRoles" => array( 
            array( "email" => $email, "name" => $recipientName, "roleName" => $templateRoleName )),
    "status" => "sent");                                                                    

$data_string = json_encode($data);  
$curl = curl_init($baseUrl . "/envelopes" );
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);                                                                  
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(                                                                          
    'Content-Type: application/json',                                                                                
    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string),
    "X-DocuSign-Authentication: $header" )                                                                       
);

$json_response = curl_exec($curl);
$status = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
if ( $status != 201 ) {
    echo "error calling webservice, status is:" . $status . "\nerror text is --> ";
    print_r($json_response); echo "\n";
    exit(-1);
}

$response = json_decode($json_response, true);
$envelopeId = $response["envelopeId"];

// --- display results
echo "Document is sent! Envelope ID = " . $envelopeId . "\n\n";
```

Comment: What "provided code" are you using? Please include a link or put more of your sw into the question.

Comment: this is the PHP code given by Docusign

Comment: I've confirmed the problem on a Window 7 system using WAMP. The example works fine from a Linux system (I just tested it). I'm continuing to investigate...

Comment: The problem on my system was lack of trusted CA certs. I've submitted an answer for that. You may have some other problem--if so, please update your question with the output of the Verbose setting from curl. Thanks.

Comment: Please also supply details on your environment: What OS, what PHP installation, are you using a pre-packaged PHP system such as WAMP or something else, etc? Since the example definitely works in environments other than yours, the problem is in your environment. That's the problem to be solved....

Answer (score 1):

Is your problem that you don't have trusted CA certificates installed?

**How to check**

Add to the example code:

```
$curl = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true); #### Added
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
```

And see what you get.

In my case, (running on Windows with WAMP), the verbose output included:

`SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate`

The fix for this is to install the trusted certificates locally. The alternative is to turn off cert checking which extremely NOT recommended!!

**Installing the trusted certificate**

1. [Download the certificates from the Curl website](http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem). Store the file locally, in the same directory as your example php software as cacert.pem
2. Add the following two options to both of your curl operations:

Search for $curl = curl_init($url); and add the code after each instance:

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CAINFO, "cacert.pem");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CAPATH, ".");
```

**Install trusted CA list at the PHP level**

Even better is to fix your PHP installation, as a whole, by configuring it to use the cacert.pem by default.

Comment: Specifically in WAMP you're going to have to add it to the config. 
File:
C:\wamp\bin\php\phpX\php.ini

Add the following:

[Curl]
curl.cainfo = "C:/wamp/cert/cacert.pem"