# Download a document from docusign envelope given documentid and envelopeid using docusign api

Tags: docusignapi

By using docusign api, I want to download the document from an envelope. I tried the code below, but it did not give me what I want.

```
en_api = new DocuSign\eSign\Api\EnvelopesApi($apiClient);
get_doc = en_api->getDocument($account_id, $document_id, $envelope_id);
```

Anyone has any idea how can this be accomplished?

Comment: What response did you get?

Comment: @CloudSeph - Please use the logging that DocuSign provides to answer Larry K's question and please follow up on other questions you have placed so that people get the appropriate feedback for helping you :-) Please follow up on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49442267/php-docusign-api-get-template/49448227#49448227

And you can capture exact JSON request posted by your PHP | API calls by following steps explained at this DocuSign support article https://support.docusign.com/guides/ndse-user-guide-api-request-logging

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem by saving the file as my_doc.pdf in my own local folder. I don't think docusign allows downloads directly.

```
file_put_contents("my_doc.pdf", file_get_contents($get_doc->getPathname()));
```

Comment: i am trying to download the file using the same way, but i do get empty file, do you have faced any such issue while working with it ?